# Парсинг json файла из json

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Есть `json` файл, данные которого после парсинга выводятся. Один из объектов хранит в себе ссылку на другой `json`-файл. В таком роде:

```
"date": "2016-06-25T13:00:00Z",
"status": "FINISHED",
"link" : {
      "homeTeam": { "href": "http://api.football-data.org/v1/teams/788"}
}
```

Сам парсер был найден в интернете, но я более и менее разобрался, и я его немного изменил, под себя

```
private class ParserJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    BufferedReader reader = null;
    String resultJson = "";

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL("http://api.football-data.org/v1/soccerseasons/424/fixtures");

            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                buffer.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            resultJson = buffer.toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultJson;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
        super.onPostExecute(strJson);

        JSONObject dataJsonObj = null;

        try {
            dataJsonObj = new JSONObject(strJson);
            JSONArray friends = dataJsonObj.getJSONArray("fixtures");

            for (int i = 0; i < friends.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject friend = friends.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject res = friend.getJSONObject("result");
                JSONObject _links = friend.getJSONObject("_links");

                int matchday = friend.getInt("matchday");

                if(matchday == 4) {
                    String date = friend.getString("date");
                    String status = friend.getString("status");
                    String homeTeamName = friend.getString("homeTeamName");
                    String awayTeamName = friend.getString("awayTeamName");
                    int goalsHomeTeam = res.getInt("goalsHomeTeam");
                    int goalsAwayTeam = res.getInt("goalsAwayTeam");

                    String homeTeamImagePath = _links.getString("homeTeam");

                    Match _match = new Match(date, status, matchday, homeTeamName, awayTeamName, goalsHomeTeam, goalsAwayTeam);
                    matches.add(_match);
                }
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Класс `ParserJSON` является вложенным. Его объект создаётся при запуске приложение

```
new ParserJSON().execute();
```

Данные из файла записываются в `ArrayList`.
Я не знаю как мне пропарсить `json`-файл и `json`-файл, ссылка на который хранится в объекте homeTeam
Помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: У вас есть URL, по нему получаете JSON, из него получаете URL. Дальше выполните ту же самую работу, но уже с новым URL. Для этого можете переписать более универсально этот класс, либо дописать другой такой же. В чем именно трудность?

Comment: @tse проблема именно в том, что я не могу сделать класс более универсальным, поэтому и пишу сюда. Как я понимаю URL мне мне нужно вытаскивать во время вытаскивания основной информации. Я просто не знаю как мне во время парсинга запарсить еще один файл

Comment: "Полить голову шампунем, потереть, смыть водой, повторить". Не надо во время. Надо сохранить URL, спокойно закончить парсинг первого файла, и затем выполнить аналогичную операцию для второго URL.